# Model-bind POST with Array of objects in NancyFx

Tags: json, data-binding, post, deserialization, nancy

I have a json object with the following structure

```
{
 ContainerType: "Box",
 Items : [{Name: "Coin", Amount: 5}, {Name: "Spyglas", Amount : 1}]   
}
```

This object has an representation in the Nancy backend system:

```
public string ContainerType {get; set}
public IEnumberable<Item> Items {get; set}
```

where Item (as expected) is a very simple object with public properties:

```
public string Name {get; set;}
public double Amount {get; set;}
```

My problem is that when I receive the Post in my module (based on NancyModule) only the string property is being binded in this line of code:

```
var model = this.databind<MyContainerModel>();
```

I've tried with changing list types to more specific (List<MyContainerModel>), to Arrays (MyContainerModel[]), but nothing seems to work.

The data-binding examples in the demo section of the git-repo for Nancy only deals with deserialization of ints, but my question is for the deserialization of arrays with javascript objects.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After a few hours I found the solution. The problem was not the Nancy part of it, it was that my ajax post did not have the right headers. adding *contentType* and *dataType* did the trick:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/add',
    type: 'POST',
    data: normalModel,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',

})
```

Hope this helps future readers!

Comment: On Nancy, lots of those errors :). Nothing wrong with code in Nancy etc. But headers and json-structures...

Comment: normalModel above needs to be in JSON format not just a JS object. To convert it use JSON.stringify(normalModel). This was getting me.