# Nancy : use array of data from POST request

Tags: .net, rest, post, nancy

I need to send an array of object from my web application to my Nancy web service in order to update my database.

Sending just an object, it works fine : in my web method, I get the data using `Request.Form.<data>.Value.Trim()`. But that doesn't work if I try to send an array of data.

So how can I get and handle an array of data in my Nancy web method?

->The serialized object I try to send : 
"data[0][Id]=56&data[0][SatisM]=1&data[0][Type]=0&data[0][Commentaire]=com&data[0][Month]=3&data[1][Id]=57&data[1][SatisM]=2&data[1][Type]=1&data[1][Commentaire]=com1&data[1][Month]=3&data[2][Id]=58&data[2][SatisM]=1&data[2][Type]=2&data[2][Commentaire]=com2&data[2][Month]=3&data[3][Id]=59&data[3][SatisM]=3&data[3][Type]=3&data[3][Commentaire]=com3&data[3][Month]=3"

-> The same but encoded
%22data%5B0%5D%5BId%5D=56&data%5B0%5D%5BSatisM%5D=1&data%5B0%5D%5BType%5D=0&data%5B0%5D%5BCommentaire%5D=com&data%5B0%5D%5BMonth%5D=3&data%5B1%5D%5BId%5D=57&data%5B1%5D%5BSatisM%5D=2&data%5B1%5D%5BType%5D=1&data%5B1%5D%5BCommentaire%5D=com1&data%5B1%5D%5BMonth%5D=3&data%5B2%5D%5BId%5D=58&data%5B2%5D%5BSatisM%5D=1&data%5B2%5D%5BType%5D=2&data%5B2%5D%5BCommentaire%5D=com2&data%5B2%5D%5BMonth%5D=3&data%5B3%5D%5BId%5D=59&data%5B3%5D%5BSatisM%5D=3&data%5B3%5D%5BType%5D=3&data%5B3%5D%5BCommentaire%5D=com3&data%5B3%5D%5BMonth%5D=3%22

Answer (score 2):

From your question I suppose you're sending data from a form as GET request. I had a similar problem, however I send my data within a POST request. Maybe it works for you, too:

To send an array, all the form elements that belong to the array need the **same** name:

**WRONG**

```
<input name="MyArray[0]" value="x" />
<input name="MyArray[1]" value="y" />
```

**RIGHT**

```
<input name="MyArray" value="x" />
<input name="MyArray" value="y" />
```

With that, Nancy will parse your data correctly. In order to be able to access it as array, you need to use [Model Binding](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Model-binding).

BTW, I didn't get arrays of objects to work with forms as data source, only arrays of primitive types. Arrays of objects work, however, when you send the data JSON formatted with XHR. But I can't say if this is possible in your case.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure from your context what you mean by 'Sending' an object (http POST?) or 'Web Method' (Nancy Module?). Perhaps some code would help clarify?

Anyway, maybe you could use Nancy's Model Binding feature. Here is another question that shows how.

[Model-bind POST with Array of objects in NancyFx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13017700/776476)